# React to dropping item out of Control with AllowDrop = true

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm new to handling Drag-n-Drop events in C# and I've confronted a problem.

I have a WinForms project with a form containing a button and a panel.
I've set panels AllowDrop property to true and added a handler for DragDrop event:

```
panel1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(panel1_DragDrop);
```

For a button I've added a MouseDown event handler that initializes DragDropEffects:

```
    void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Button).BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop((sender as Button), DragDropEffects.All);
    }
```

I have no problem with DragDrop event raised by Panel;

My question is how can I handle event of user dropping the item outside the area where AllowDrop property set to true?
Suppose I want to set Buttons BorderStyle back to FixedSingle when user while perfoming dragging releases the mouse button outside of my Panel - what event should I handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the panel's [`DragLeave` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragleave.aspx).

Comment: DragLeave event is not exactly what I'm looking for, - I'm looking for an event similar to DragDrop event but for the area where Dropping is not allowed. I can handle DragLeave event but it'll trigger despite the user's still continuing dragging.

Comment: @MikhailTregubov: Doesn't `DoDragDrop()` return `None` in that case?  Note that `DoDragDrop()` is a blocking call that runs the message loop.